I am using .NET Framework and my API calls from frontend are showing error of 404
I have already created the APIs in and they are declared in constants.cs file as such:
#region Department Saving APIs
public static string DepartmentSave = HrisBaseUrl + "Department/Save";
#endregion

#region Department Updating APIs
public static string DepartmentUpdate = HrisBaseUrl + "Department/Update";
#endregion

#region Department Searching APIs
public static string DepartmentSearch = HrisBaseUrl + "Department/Search";
#endregion

#region Department Deleting APIs
public static string DepartmentDelete = HrisBaseUrl + "Department/Delete";
#endregion

and I wrote some code in controller file to use these apis for frontend:
public class DepartmentController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Department_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            var userData = Security.GetUserSecurityData(Request.Cookies);
            var departmentList = await APICall.PostData<DepartmentModel>(Constants.DepartmentSearch, new
            {
                UserId = userData.UserID,
                Username = userData.UserName,
                Key = userData.Key,
                BusinessUnitId = userData.nBusinessUnitID,
                BranchId = userData.nBranchID,
            });
            if (departmentList != null)
            {
                if (departmentList.Status != false)
                {
                    if (departmentList.Results.Count > 0)
                    {
                        return Json(departmentList.Results.OrderByDescending(o => o.Id).ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                }
            }
            //khali list
            return Json(new List<DepartmentModel>().ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }

        catch
        {
            //statement repeat kiu?
            return Json(new List<DepartmentModel>().ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
    public async Task<ActionResult> Department_Search([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var emptyResult = Json(new List<DepartmentModel>().ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        try
        {
            var userData = Security.GetUserSecurityData(Request.Cookies);

            var departmentList = await APICall.PostData<DepartmentModel>(Constants.DepartmentSearch, new
            {
                UserId = userData.UserID,
                Username = userData.UserName,
                Key = userData.Key,
                BusinessUnitId = userData.nBusinessUnitID,
                DepartmentId = userData.NDepartmentId,
                BranchId = userData.nBranchID,
            });
            if (departmentList != null)
            {
                if (departmentList.Status != false)
                {
                    if (departmentList.Results.Count > 0)
                    {
                        return Json(departmentList.Results.OrderByDescending(o => o.Id).ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                }
            }
            return emptyResult;
        }
        catch
        {
            return emptyResult;
        }
    }
    public async Task<ActionResult> Department_Delete([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string searchQuery)
    {
        var emptyResult = Json(new { Success = false, Message = "Failed to delete department." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        try
        {
            var userData = Security.GetUserSecurityData(Request.Cookies);

            var deleteResult = await APICall.PostData<DepartmentModel>(Constants.DepartmentDelete, new
            {
                UserId = userData.UserID,
                Username = userData.UserName,
                Key = userData.Key,
                BusinessUnitId = userData.nBusinessUnitID,
                BranchId = userData.nBranchID,
            });
            if (deleteResult != null && deleteResult.Status)
            {
                return Json(new { Success = true, Message = "Department deleted successfully." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            return Json(new { Success = false, Message = "Department not found or could not be deleted." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Any Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

            //Delete Fail?
            return emptyResult;
        }
    }
}

The code looks fine but none of the APIs are working on frontend. Can anyone point out or help me fix the error here?
I tried removing errors and removing useless declarations, asked my seniors if there is something wrong here.
from what I understand is that I am missing something to take input from the user but the APIs are there already I think I don't need to add that part.

You're missing your route attribute and your verb-attributes. Perhaps read up on Attribute routing for REST APIs

All your ActionResult are missing route . There is no way the routing will be mapped to the respective endpoint.
